# What is wrong with my method of finding the probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

One way to solve this and my book has done it is by :

[image]

---

This is a well known way, but I have a different method, and it seems logical to me (but I don't know what the mistake is). And yes it's wrong, but I don't understand what's wrong with my following method :

For 1 component the mean is $E(X)=2.5$ so for 5 components it's :

$$E(5X)=5E(X)=5(2.5)=12.5$$

So for 5 items we can say :

$$\lambda= 1/E(5X)= 1/12.5$$

$$X ~ Expo (1/12.5)$$

$$P(T \geq 3)=1-e^{-3/12.5}$$
$$P(T \geq3)=0.21$$

Which is not the same as in the book. Please help me, what is wrong with my method.

Comment: $5\cdot 2.5 \neq 1.25$

Comment: @Ritz ,fixed typo ....I used 12.5 , but when I started typing I kept on using 1.25, I was looking at my book and typing. I used 12.5.

Comment: The random variable $5X$ has no connection to the lifetime of the system.

Comment: @AndréNicolas , UMMM I don't understand. But if X has a exponential distribution , why not 5X? And the way I found the rate parameter is correct I believe.

Comment: I did not say that $5X$ doesn't have exponential distribution. It does. But the lifetime of the system is $\min(X_1,\dots,X_5)$, where the $X_i$ are the lifetimes of the components. It is not $5X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make the problem simpler by considering only two component lifetimes $X_1$ and $X_2$, both of which are exponentially distributed. The expectation of the sum $\mathbb{E}[X_1 + X_2]$ is *not* the expected lifetime of a system having both components concurrently. Instead, it is the expected value of a random variable $Y = X_1 + X_2$, which is the sum of the lifetimes of both components. In fact, $Y$ represents the lifetime of a system with the two components running *sequentially* (with one component replacing the other after the first "died"). What the problem is asking is for a system in which all five components are *concurrently* operating at the same time.

Comment: If we were interested (which we are not) in the lifetime with the components running sequentially, then indeed the mean would be the sum of the means. But the *distribution* (with $2$ components, or $5$) is not exponential.

Comment: Andre, indeed but I think clarifying the error in the $\mathbb{E}[5X]$ was sufficient to illustrate why the proposed method was wrong. From my understanding, the questioner was interested in what was wrong with her method and was not asking for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_5$ be the lifetimes of the components. Let $Y=\min(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_5)$. Then $Y$ is the lifetime of the system.

We have $Y\gt y$ precisely if $X_i\gt y$ for $i=1,2,\dots,5$.  Thus by independence
$$\Pr(Y\gt y)=\prod_1^5\Pr(X_i\gt y)=e^{-5\lambda y}.$$
It follows that the lifetime of the system has exponential distribution with parameter $5\lambda$. This means that the lifetime of the system is, in our case, exponentially distributed with mean $\frac{2.5}{5}$.